# Unanswered Undefined Symbols for architecture x86_64

Tags: xcode4, undefined, x86-64, symbols

I'm getting errors, all : "Undefined Symbols for architecture x86_64".

the simplest class where this error happens is class named Peaking that computes equalizations.

here is my class definition peaking

```
#ifndef _PEAKING_
#define _PEAKING_

#include "IPlugBase.h"
#include "IGraphics.h"

class Peaking
{
public:
  Peaking()
  {
      a = new double[3];
      b = new double[3];

      previousx1=0;
      previouspreviousx1=0;
  }
  ~Peaking() {}

  double* a;
  double* b;

  void ComputeParams(double G, double fc, double Q, double fs);
  double ComputeAudio(double x);

    double previouspreviousx1;
    double previousx1;


private:

};

#endif
```

and here is the implementation

```
#include <math.h>
#include "defines.hpp"
#include "Peaking.h"

void Peaking::ComputeParams(double G, double fc, double Q, double fs)
{

double K = tan((M_PI * fc)/fs);
double V0 = pow(10,(G/20.));

//Invert gain if a cut
if (V0 < 1)
    V0 = 1/V0;

double a1, a2, b0, b1, b2;

////////////////////////////
//   BOOST
////////////////////////////
double K2 = pow(K,2.);

double divQ = 1/Q;
double z1 = (divQ*K);
double divz2 = 1/(1 + z1 + K2);
double z3 = ((V0*divQ)*K);
double divz4 = 1/(1 + z3 + K2);


if( G > 0 )
{
    b0 = (1 + z3 + K2) * divz2;
    b1 =        (2 * (K2 - 1)) * divz2;
    b2 = (1 - z3 + K2) * divz2;
    a1 = b1;
    a2 = (1 - z1 + K2) * divz2;
}
////////////////////////////
//    CUT
////////////////////////////
else
{
    b0 = (1 + z1 + K2) * divz4;
    b1 = (2 * (K2 - 1)) * divz4;
    b2 = (1 - z1 + K2) * divz4;
    a1 = b1;
    a2 = (1 - z3 + K2) * divz4;
}

a[0] = 1;
a[1] = a1;
a[2] = a2;

b[0] = b0;
b[1] = b1;
b[2] = b2;

}


double Peaking::ComputeAudio(double x)
{
    // E:\Programmation\#Audio\#EQ\dfilt_df2.gif
    double srg = a[2];

    double x1 = x - a[1] * previousx1 - a[2] * previouspreviousx1;

    double y = x1 * b[0] + previousx1 * b[1] +  previouspreviousx1 * b[2];

    previouspreviousx1 = previousx1;
    previousx1 = x1;


    return y;


}
```

here is the error list:

> ```
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
>   "OnOff::OnOff(IPlugBase*, int, int, int, IBitmap*, IBitmap*, IChannelBlend::EBlendMethod)", referenced from:
>       AutoEQ::AutoEQ(IPlugInstanceInfo) in AutoEQ.o
>   "Peaking::ComputeAudio(double)", referenced from:
>       AutoEQ::traiterLearning(int) in AutoEQ.o
>       AutoEQ::ProcessDoubleReplacing(double**, double**, int) in AutoEQ.o
>   "Peaking::ComputeParams(double, double, double, double)", referenced from:
>       AutoEQ::traiterLearning(int) in AutoEQ.o
>   "FFTOoura::rdft(int, int, double*, int*, double*)", referenced from:
>       AutoEQ::traiterLearning(int) in AutoEQ.o
>   "vtable for ProgressBar", referenced from:
>       ProgressBar::ProgressBar(IPlugBase*, int, int, int, IBitmap, IBitmap, IChannelBlend::EBlendMethod) in AutoEQ.o
>   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>   "vtable for EQClass", referenced from:
>       EQClass::EQClass(IPlugBase*, int) in AutoEQ.o
>   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>   "vtable for VUmetre", referenced from:
>       VUmetre::VUmetre(IPlugBase*, int, int, int, IBitmap, IBitmap, IChannelBlend::EBlendMethod) in AutoEQ.o
>   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
>   "vtable for MyButton", referenced from:
>       MyButton::MyButton(IPlugBase*, int, int, int, IBitmap*, IChannelBlend::EBlendMethod) in AutoEQ.o
>   NOTE: a missing vtable usually means the first non-inline virtual member function has no definition.
> ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
> clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
> ```

if I put the core of the function "double Peaking::ComputeAudio(double x)" in the class, one error disappears.

If i put the body of the virtual function "draw" of Vumetre, another error goes away. **So i cannot put some main bodies functions in the .cpp file, how come ?**

thanks for help

Jeff

Comment: just to be clear, are you sure that your cpp files are being compiled at all?

Comment: i didn't say i had to put *all* the functions in the .h file but some only

Comment: Also i'm using WDL-OL to create Audio Plugins in various architectures (APP, AU, VST, AAX, etc) and so far APP is working ok, but i have the issue when trying to compile AU plugins

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found out : some .cpp files were not present in the "Build Phase/Compile source" panel

now it's working!

i'm relatively new to developping on OS X thus this noob error.

Jeff